# Left join with where clause is not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get all the users in my DB which have or do not have requests of friendship, but if they do have requests of friendship, I do not want the ones where a particular user is part of that request of friendship.
My stored procedure is named getNotFriendsOfUser.
This is the query :

```
select * from user a left join request b on a.idPerson = b.idRequester
inner join persona c on a.idPerson = c.idPerson 
where b.idRequester <>  @idPerson
```

There are no friendship relationships on my database and there are more than 10 users to test, but I do not find WHY this query is always returning an empty set of values.

This does give results btw :

```
select * from user a left join request b on a.idPerson = b.idRequester
    inner join persona c on a.idPerson = c.idPerson
```

Help?

Comment: post a SQLFiddle with data

Comment: I think this is related to `@idPerson`, but without info, I can't tell.

Comment: you are inner joining to persona, are you sure that's populated?

Comment: the  where clause was making all my results void, for left join as per the sql standar you have to put something like where key is null when using left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then use a subquery or derived table with your left join for the results you want to omit and exclude them on the primary key.